# Wrong results in database when filtering data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a problem in the last 10 days; I tried many times but I found no solution.

I'm developing a Restaurant POS.

I am creating a report for daily sales; I'm facing a problem in a SQL query that gets data for the daily sales.

My restaurant's opening time is 13:00 and its closing time is 04:00 tomorrow.

Like this:

- Opening date & time is =14.08.2019 & 13:00
- Closing date & Time is =15.08.2019 & 04:00

We have 24 hour time format.

I'm trying this SQL query. But I always get this result:

```
Total sale = 0.00
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is the SQL query you are running? What type of SQL is this (e.g. MS SQL MySQL)? Do you have an example of some of the data rows that you would expect to be returned?

Comment: using SQL Server 2014

Comment: I try rhis Query 
`ALTER procedure [dbo].[USP_Select_sale_Baseon_Employee]
(
@Emid int,
@Dateofbil  datetime,
@Todate  datetime,
@Fromtime time(7),
@Endtime time(7)
)
as
begin
SELECT        
   coalesce(sum( c.[Receableamount]),0) as 'recevable'
  FROM [dbo].[Customer_Bill_Details] c
  where [EmID]=@Emid and      [Billdate]>=@Dateofbil and BillTime>=@Fromtime and [Billdate]<=@Todate and BillTime<=@Endtime
  end`

Comment: Try breaking down that procedure e.g. start by running a plain SQL query where you define the parameters. Assuming that returns nothing start taking away the WHERE clauses until you do return data.

Comment: what is your database?

Comment: Our Database is SQL Server 2014

Comment: SELECT        
   coalesce(sum( c.[Receableamount]),0) as 'recevable'
  FROM [dbo].[Customer_Bill_Details] c
  where [EmID]='1' and ([Billdate]>='10-08-2019 00:00:00' and BillTime>='13:18') and ([Billdate]<='11-08-2019 00:00:00' and BillTime<='04:10')
  Here is My Query it still Show result Sale=0

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to pass three parameters (date related) to your procedure: `@Year`, `@Month` and `@Day`. And finally write the select statement inside the procedure as below:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(c.[Receableamount]), 0) AS 'receivable' 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Customer_Bill_Details] c 
WHERE 
    YEAR(DATEADD(HH, -4, (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Billdate), BillTime)))) = @Year
    AND MONTH(DATEADD(HH, -4, (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Billdate), BillTime)))) = @Month
    AND DAY(DATEADD(HH, -4, (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Billdate), BillTime)))) = @Day
```

As you can see I have less 4 hours from your Billdate which will pull your all daily transaction from 2 different days to 1 single day and filtering by Year/Month/Day(Single) will provide you your expected results. You can add other necessary filters to the script as per your requirement.

Comment: I have two different column in database one for DATE and second for TIME.

Comment: Give a sample date and time value

Comment: BillDate=2019-08-10 00:00:00.000    and billTime=22:28:38.0000000

Comment: I dont know how can i add image of sample data

Comment: I got it. not required image.

Comment: Oh Thanks Sir Please give me Any Solution.

Comment: Can you please check the edited script? I just merged your BillDate and BillTime value to make it date time and kept the previous logic as it was.

Comment: Sir Where is edited Script. Please Share in comment selection so i easily find out result thanks .

Comment: Script edited in answer. Check, you will find the changes.